# JPQL one-to-many query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Entity A has a collection of some entities of type B. Type B is not aware (and should not be) of what type A is. I'd like to query for A which has at least one B with certain property.

As for the mappings I use simple one-to-many and a join-column inside it at the A mapping side.

Yet, when I do this using JPQL I cannot really use the JPA-generated column a_id since it's not a field of B - and therefore results in PropetyNotFound - jpa exception. Is there a method to use that column not having to define a property in the entity itself?

Entity A mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <package>com.example</package>

    <entity class="B" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <id name="seqid">
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
            </id>
            <basic name="identifier" />
            <basic name="payload" />
            <version name="version" />
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="A" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <id name="seqid">
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
            </id>
            <one-to-many name="bset">
                <join-column name="a_id"
                    referenced-column-name="seqid" />
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all />
                </cascade>
            </one-to-many>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Short and simple: if you reference it, you should define it in your entities.

Comment: Even if logically and code-wise it makes no sense? Why JPA does not force me to define such field? Maybe there's other way like some sort of "in" clause?

Comment: Well, `a_id` is readily available via `A.id`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to select A's which have B's with a certain property set to a certain value.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example query you like to execute and which fails? From my experience, you should be able to join `B` and use a it a where clause normally.

Comment: The problem was I must have used join clause on this set. Without using it, the operation was failing. Thanks!

Comment: Glad the indication helped. Please post that answer as a real answer (and accept it) so the system doesn't show this question as unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you're using join clause on the set. Without it query will be constructed with no errors but this will fail with a strange error when executed. So the correct query would look like

```
select a from A a join a.setB b where b in (select c from B where B.x = 'x');
```

this will be successful but

```
select a from A a where a.setB in (select c from B where B.x = 'x');
```

will fail with no apparent reason.